# Swift + macOS + Xcode : Access array of key value pairs created in a class from ContentView

Tags: arrays, swift, class, key-value

I have written some code that successfully reads a JSON file into what I believe is an array of key value pairs with 5 values associated with each key.
The JSON file is read in during the creation of a class and appears to work.  In ContentView I would like to be able to step through keys (which are dates) and values, probably with a ForEach loop.  Unfortunately I am not able to access the array of key value pairs from the ContentView.  The print statement in the Class prints out what I would expect.  In the ContentView arrayname.count returns 0.  I would guess I am overlooking some simple thing but sometimes when you look at something for too long you miss the obvious.
If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

The ForEach was my way of trying to determine how to access individual members of vooData such as the date, which is the key, or a specific value such as closing.

Below is my test code.
Regards,
Chris

Examples of my JSON file and the result of the print statement in the class ReadData are as follows.

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "VOO",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-09-22",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2021-09-22": {
            "1. open": "402.1700",
            "2. high": "405.8500",
            "3. low": "401.2600",
            "4. close": "403.9000",
            "5. volume": "5979811"
        },

Stock(timeSeriesDaily: [

"2011-07-22": ReadJSONData.TimeSeriesDaily
(Open: "61.5000", 
High: "61.6000", 
Low: "61.2000", 
Close: "61.5500", 
Volume: “180400"
), 

"2014-06-18": ReadJSONData.TimeSeriesDaily
(
Open: "178.5900", 
High: "179.9700", 
Low: "178.1700", 
Close: "179.8700", 
Volume: “501900"
), 

"2015-09-18": ReadJSONData.TimeSeriesDaily
(
Open: "180.4100", 
High: "182.0400", 
Low: "179.6900", 
Close: "180.1300", 
Volume: “3205186"
)
])



import SwiftUI
struct Stock: Codable {
    let timeSeriesDaily: [String: TimeSeriesDaily]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
    }
}
struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    let Open, High, Low, Close: String
    let Volume: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Open = "1. open"
        case High = "2. high"
        case Low = "3. low"
        case Close = "4. close"
        case Volume = "5. volume"
    }
}
class ReadData {
//class ReadData: ObservableObject  {
//    @Published var tmpData  = [Stock]()
    var tmpData : [Stock] = []
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VOO", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        let tmpData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data!)
        print(tmpData!)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
//    @ObservedObject var vooData = ReadData()
    let readClass = ReadData()
    @State var vooData : [Stock] = ReadData().tmpData
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    print(vooData.count)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few things that I can address here, but I'm troubled that `JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data!)` actually works. It sounds like what you actually want is `[Stock]`. Can you include a sample of the actual JSON data? And maybe describe what you're trying to see in your `ForEach`?

Comment: What you've posted is not valid JSON. Can you please post the actual JSON file you're trying to decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON that you've included isn't really valid. I'm making an assumption that it actually looks something like this:

```
{
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2021-09-22": {
            "1. open": "402.1700",
            "2. high": "405.8500",
            "3. low": "401.2600",
            "4. close": "403.9000",
            "5. volume": "5979811"
        }
    }
}
```

If that's the case, then you can make some slight alterations to your code and have it work.

- It looks like you had initially tried to use `ObservableObject` -- that *is* what you should use.
- In your original code, you used `let tmpData =` but you never set `self.tmpData`
- Using `do/try/catch` instead of `try?` is preferable because you can actually print an error if one occurs.
- It's unclear exactly what you're trying to display, but I included an example of a `ForEach` which converts the dictionary to key/value pairs and then displays the opening price.

```
struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    let Open, High, Low, Close: String
    let Volume: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Open = "1. open"
        case High = "2. high"
        case Low = "3. low"
        case Close = "4. close"
        case Volume = "5. volume"
    }
}
class ReadData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var tmpData  = Stock(timeSeriesDaily: [:])
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VOO", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.tmpData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data)
            print(self.tmpData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vooData = ReadData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(vooData.tmpData.timeSeriesDaily.map { ($0.key,$0.value) }, id: \.0) { keyValuePair in
                VStack {
                    Text(keyValuePair.0)
                    Text("Open: \(keyValuePair.1.Open)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Can you explain the comment about never setting self.tmpData.  I assume it may be part of the reason ContentView did not get the data.  In addition, is the data contained in tmpData an array of key value pairs?  If so, is your conversion taking it from an array of key value pairs and converting it to a dictionary where there are just keys and values?

Comment: "Can you explain the comment about never setting self.tmpData" Sure -- if you don't set `self.tmpData`, it never gets a value. `let tmpData` is *not* the same as `self.tmpData` -- the scope of `let tmpData` is just for that function. `self.tmpData` sets a property on the class.

Comment: "is the data contained in tmpData an array of key value pairs" -- basically. It's a `Dictionary`. But, a Dictionary is not just an "array of key value pairs" -- that's what I used `map` to do.

Comment: If this answered your question, please use the green checkmark to accept it and also consider upvoting using the arrow if you found the answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight error in your `init`

You have

```
class ReadData {
    var tmpData : [Stock] = []
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VOO", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        let tmpData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data!)

     // ^^^^^^^^^^^ - don't think this should be let

        print(tmpData!)
    }
}
```

but I don't think you want the `let` on the tmpData inside of `loadData`.  I think you intend to assign this to the instance variable, not a local variable.

Try:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  JSONSample
//
//  Created by Scott Thompson on 9/23/21.
//

import SwiftUI

let jsonData = """
{
    \"Meta Data\": {
        \"1. Information\": \"Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes\",
        \"2. Symbol\": \"VOO\",
        \"3. Last Refreshe\": \"2021-09-22\",
        \"4. Output Size\": \"Full size\",
    \"5. Time Zone\": \"US/Eastern\"
    },
    \"Time Series (Daily)\": {
        \"2021-09-22\": {
            \"1. open\": \"402.1700\",
            \"2. high\": \"405.8500\",
            \"3. low\": \"401.2600\",
            \"4. close\": \"403.9000\",
            \"5. volume\": \"5979811\"
        },
    }
}
"""

struct Stock: Codable {
    let timeSeriesDaily: [String: TimeSeriesDaily]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
    }
}

struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    let Open, High, Low, Close: String
    let Volume: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Open = "1. open"
        case High = "2. high"
        case Low = "3. low"
        case Close = "4. close"
        case Volume = "5. volume"
    }
}

class ReadData {
    let tmpData : [Stock]
    init() {
        let data = jsonData.data(using: .utf8)

        if let parsedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data!) {
            tmpData = [parsedData]
        } else {
            tmpData = []
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var vooData : [Stock] = ReadData().tmpData
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    debugPrint(vooData)
                    print(vooData.count)
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(PreviewLayout.sizeThatFits)
            .padding()
            .previewDisplayName("Default preview")
    }
}
```

Comment: You're completely right about the `let tmpData` vs setting the class property, which I also addressed in my answer. However, your answer omits the fact that the OP was using an asynchronous URL request to get the JSON data and replaces it with a non-asynchronous call. Without annotating `ReadData` with `ObservableObject`, the `ContentView` will not know that `tmpData` has been set and will not display the data correctly.

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  I have learned a lot and now have functioning code.